# Probability of a maximum being greater than a number. Inequality

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, measure-theory, random-variables

Imagine we have a seqence of (positive) absolutely continuous random variables $X_n$ and we know $\sup_n X_n$ is a measurable random variable and $\sup_n X_n < \infty$, i.e. there is a maximum one. Is the following true?

$$P\left( \sup_{n} X_n \geq a \right) = P\left( \bigcup_n \left\{ X_n \geq a\right\} \right).$$

If not, is then the following true?
$$P\left( \sup_{n} X_n \geq a \right) \leq P\left( \bigcup_n \left\{ X_n \geq a\right\} \right).$$

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
P\biggl(\sup X_n \geq a\biggr) &= 1 - P\biggl(\sup X_n < a  \biggr) \\
&= 1 - P\biggl(\bigcap_n\{X_n < a\}  \biggr) \\
&= 1 - \biggl[1 - P\biggl(\bigcup_n\{X_n \geq a\}   \biggr)\biggr] \\
&= P\biggl(\bigcup_n\{X_n \geq a\}   \biggr)
\end{align*}

Comment: It's generally not true that $\sup X_n<a$ is equivalent to $\bigcup_n\{X_n<a\}$. For example consider the deterministic random variables $X_n=a-1/n$.

Comment: In the equation we have $\sup_n X_n \geq a$, not $<$, in that case $\sup_n X_n < a$ is equivalent to $\bigcap_n \{X_n < a\}$. But you mean that the above argument is wrong then? I can't find the mistake.